# iMovie export unsync and without transitions music

Tags: export, imovie

I have done a 1 hour and 36 min long movie on my weeding and it's made of around 80 "clips", where in some places the original sound is used and in some places external sound is placed instead. In some places iMovie text boxes is used and in some places the video has filters and slow motion (so a lot of random filters, effects, etc and chapters).

So my problem? When I export is, regardless if its to iDVD, iTunes, MOV HD720 or 1080, and regardless if its "finilized" first or not, or if its shared to "media library", the transitions is not working (un sync) and the sound is fading out to 0% during all the transitions before up to the original level. This in the final film.

When in the "project view" looking and listening, everything is just perfect. As soon as I finilize the project, or export it, it doenst work (not even in the project preview after export). I also tested to install miDVD pro (10$) and WonderShare DVD Creator (39$) to just sharing the project to them, but the result was the same.

I have macbook 13, moutain lion, iMovie 11, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be caused by using free trial version. You can try the fullversion of miDVD pro (10$) and WonderShare DVD Creator (39$), if it doesn't work, you can ask for refund.